# how to replace a value which is not recognized by vba?

Tags: vba

I have a formatting issue with the VBA code. I have a process where I have to copy some value from PDF file into excel where the hyphen sign (-) comes a little large such as "−". I need this character to be replaced by normal hyphen. However when I am trying to put this "−" sign in VBA, it is showing "?".

How can I get this sorted?

Comment: Maybe it is `Chr(150)` ? Or it could be Unicode `ChrW(&H2013)` ?

Comment: Thanks for that. But I am afraid I do not have any idea to use that in a code. Can you please give an example to use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way out of this situation. I just declared a variant with this character and replaced the exact character required by VBA.

My code looks like this now and it is working fine.

```
Sub replace_test()


Dim a As Variant

a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value


Selection.Range("E1:E14").Select
Selection.Replace What:=a, Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False


End Sub
```

Also please let me know if there is another way out.

Comment: `Selection.Range("E1:E14").Select` may not select the range `E1:E14`.  It's relative to selection - your saying range `E1:E14` within your selection, not within the range of cells on the worksheet.  For example, if you select `A1:E14` then your code will select `E1:E14`, but if you select `B1:F14` then your entire selection is off by one column and it select the range `F1:F14`, select range `A2:E15` and it selects `E2:E15` as you've offset by 1 row.  Select `O84:Y99` and it select `S84:S97`.  It might be the result you're after though.

Comment: I'd suggest using `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").range("E1:E14").Replace What:=....` instead.  No need to select anything and it will look at `E1:14` on the correct sheet.

Comment: Thanks Darren. It was my early days of coding to use select statement that much. ( I know I checked this website after lot many days).